# Regular expression to match SomeWord_SomeSecondWord_SomeThirdWord

Tags: c#, regex

Ok so I'm the absolute worst regular expression writer on the planet. Figured this great community could help me out after 15 minutes of bashing my head off the desk and getting nowhere.

I know this is simple, but I need a regular expression that matches the conditions of:

```
SomeWord_SomeSecondWord
```

**or**

```
SomeWord_SomeSecondWord_SomeThirdWord
```

**In plain english:**

- two or three words (set of letters) separated by underscores.
- Each word block must start with a capital letter, contain at least two characters and contain only letters a-z.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to write a regular expression to match unit testing method names for StyleCop/ReSharper validation. I have an absolute mental block when it comes to regex.

Comment: The book "Mastering Regular Expressions" really helped me. Understanding a small number of core "letters" in the "regular expressions alphabet" can go along way to enabling you to handle most of the patterns out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@"^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+(?:_[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+){1,2}$"
```

The `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+` ensures it starts with a capital letter, and the usage of `+` will ensure at least one other character, which satisfies the requirement of the 2 character minimum.

Here's an example of it in action:

```
string[] inputs =
{
    "SomeWord", "SomeFirstWord_SomeSecondWord",
    "SomeWord_SomeSecondWord_SomeThirdWord", "SomeWord_Some2ndWord"
};

string pattern = @"^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+(?:_[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+){1,2}$";

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern), input);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `+` instead of `*` to match at least two characters.

Comment: @Brian yes, that's right. I updated it a few seconds after my initial post :)

Comment: +1 This is good answer, but there is no need to use the `?` lazy modifier.